# Set variable in content script according to message passed from BG page - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I've sent a request from my content script and received a response from my background page successfully. Now I want to set a variable in my content script - based on the response. That's where I'm having trouble. Should be simple enough.... I guess I must be getting the syntax wrong. Here's what's in my content script:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
if (response.farewell == "goodbye") {
      wasPolite = "yes";
}
else if (response.farewell == "goaway") {
      wasPolite = "no";
    }
else {
wasPolite = "maybe";
}
});
alert(wasPolite);
```

Console shows `goaway` as the response, but `wasPoite` remains undefined.

Comment: Where are you testing the value of wasPolite? I imagine this is a scope issue. Could you post a little more code showing the scope of the wasPolite variable and where it's defined and subsequently tested?

Comment: It's defined right there in the code above, as a global variable on the page where this script is injected and that's all. It's tested on the very next line following the above code. I tried to `alert(wasPolite)` but no dice...

Comment: If you define var wasPolite = ''; before the chrome.extension.... and it's still not alerting the correct value then I'd ask is the chrome.extension.sendRequest() function asynchronous? If so you may be alerting wasPolite before the request has had time to callback. @Ruup is probably on track suggesting that wasPolite will only have it's value after the sendRequest has actually finished thereby triggering the callback.

Comment: @Brad, you're right. I put my alert inside the response function, and now it works. I forgot about it being asynchronous - Doh!
Put that in an answer if you like, and I'll accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define:

```
var wasPolite = '';
```

Before the:

```
chrome.extension....
```

and it's still not alerting the correct value then I'd ask is the **chrome.extension.sendRequest()** function asynchronous? If so you may be alerting wasPolite before the request has had time to callback. @Ruup is probably on track suggesting that wasPolite will only have it's value after the sendRequest has actually finished thereby triggering the callback